# Using ARC and the -fno-objc-arc flags, a better way?

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to the iOS dev scene, and I've chosen to build my first app for the iPhone using the latest iOS version. It supports ARC, and for a newbie, not to have to deal with retain, release, autorelease and similar concerns is mostly appreciated. Than again, I'm importing some 3rd party classes to add functionality to my app that are not ARC compliant.

So for those files I'm using the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag, my questions, is it ok to do so? Does it have any influence on the app overall performance? I could go ahead and try to rewrite the code to support ARC, is it worth the trouble?

Thanks in advance for your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the accepted way. I include the excellent [Nimbus for iOS](http://nimbuskit.info/) framework in my app and that's all I needed to do to turn ARC off for Nimbus. Just do it and don't worry.

Comment: In a somewhat related vein, Nimbus does have an arc branch.

git checkout arc

https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/tree/arc

^_^

Comment: Yup! I can hardly wait until that goes mainstream!

Comment: That arc branch is now merged into master! Whoo.